# Как расположить текст ровно

Tags: html, css

У меня есть текст, который должен быть одинаковым, но получается вот так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как сделать чтобы по высоте они были одинаковыми?

```
<div class="block-3"> <br>
    <h1 class="block-3-text1"><b><i>Ссылки</i></b></h1> <br><br><br><br>
    <a href=""><h3 class="block-3-text1-2"><b><i>VK</i></b></h3></a> <br><br>
    <a href=""><h3 class="block-3-text1-2"><b><i>Discord</i></b></h3></a> <br><br>
    <a href=""><h3 class="block-3-text1-2"><b><i>Gmail</i></b></h3></a> <br><br>
    <a href=""><h3 class="block-3-text1-2"><b><i>Donate</i></b></h3></a> <br><br>

    <h1 class="block-3-text2"><b><i>Остальное</i></b></h1> <br><br><br><br>
    <a href=""><h3 class="block-3-text2-2"><b><i>Магазин</i></b></h3></a> <br><br>
</div>
```

```
.block-3 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 550px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(98, 0, 167), rgb(15, 0, 103));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(98, 0, 167), rgb(15, 0, 103));
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(98, 0, 167), rgb(15, 0, 103));
}

.block-3-text1 {
    font-size: 35px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10%;
    margin-top: 20px;
    color: white;
}

.block-3-text1-2 {
    font-size: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10%;
    color: #DCDCDC;
}

.block-3-text2 {
    font-size: 35px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 20%;
    margin-top: 20px;
    color: white;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

.block-3-text2-2 {
    font-size: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 20%;
    color: #DCDCDC;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Ваш код это что-то с чем-то, именно по этой причине многие прошли мимо вашей проблемы, так навертеть в html и css ещё нужно суметь. После его анализа даже объяснять что-либо опустились руки

Comment: Зачем тег <b> на H1 и H4, если они и так имеют эти стили по умолчанию??? font-style: bold;

Comment: №;№ть! Как можно было дойти до позиционирования, но при этом забить на примитив основ css ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В первую очередь убрать теги `<br>`, убрать такие теги как `<i>` и `<b>`, это все можно задавать через css. Так же разделить все на подблоки. Постараться соблюдать логическую(иерархическую) цепочку элементов на странице.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 550px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(98, 0, 167), rgb(15, 0, 103));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(98, 0, 167), rgb(15, 0, 103));
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(98, 0, 167), rgb(15, 0, 103));
  display: flex;
}

.btn{
  color: white ;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;  /* Я центрировал каждый блок относительно друг друга и body */
  font-style: italic; /* Через css можно задать всему блоку наклон*/
}

.btn a{
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #DCDCDC;  
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn ul{
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">       
        <div class="btn adress">
            <h1>Ссылки</h1> 
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">VK</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Discord</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Gmail</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Donate</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="btn more">
            <h1>Остальное</h1>
            <ul> 
                <li><a href="">Магазин</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: А что делать если линия появляется между верхнем блоком и нижнем(по которому я задал вопрос)? Убирал display и все нормально было. Фотографию прикреплю к вопросу

Comment: Скорее всего там у вас ещё один блок мб? Откройте консоль разработчика нажав F12 - после пройдите в Elements - далее пройдите по структуре html документа по блокам, посмотрите что к чему